# Surround XML elements with CDATA section via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

I am trying to add a `<![CDATA[]]>` to wrap a group of elements.

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<params>
  <param dataType="java.lang.String">respID</param>
  <param dataType="java.lang.Date">2015-11-04</param>
  <param dataType="java.lang.String">

     <XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ><P_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT>
<XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ>
    <P_ACTION>CREATE</P_ACTION>
    <p_activity_version_id>12</p_activity_version_id>
</XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ>
</P_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT>
</XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ>

  </param>
</params>
```

**Desired output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<params>
  <param dataType="java.lang.String">respID</param>
  <param dataType="java.lang.Date">2015-11-04</param>
  <param dataType="java.lang.String">
<![CDATA[
     <XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ><P_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT>
<XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ>
    <P_ACTION>CREATE</P_ACTION>
    <p_activity_version_id>12</p_activity_version_id>
</XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ>
</P_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT>
</XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ>
]]>
  </param>
</params>
```

Basically when I have child elements for element `param`, I need to wrap the child elements inside CDATA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Given this input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<params>
  <param dataType="java.lang.String">respID</param>
  <param dataType="java.lang.Date">2015-11-04</param>
  <param dataType="java.lang.String">

    <XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ><P_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT>
      <XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ>
        <P_ACTION>CREATE</P_ACTION>
        <p_activity_version_id>12</p_activity_version_id>
      </XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ>
    </P_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT>
    </XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ>

  </param>
</params>
```

**This XSLT will wrap `param` child elements in CDATA:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This XSLT will wrap `param` element contents in CDATA:-->
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="param[*]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>    
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**And produce this output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<params>
  <param dataType="java.lang.String">respID</param>
  <param dataType="java.lang.Date">2015-11-04</param>
  <param dataType="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[<XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ>
         <P_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT>
            <XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ>
               <P_ACTION>CREATE</P_ACTION>
               <p_activity_version_id>12</p_activity_version_id>
            </XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ>
         </P_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT>
      </XX_IL_OLM_COMP_ELEMENT_OBJ>]]></param>
</params>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thanks kjhuges.

Comment: Can share your knowledge on: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810019/covert-an-xml-which-contains-lt-gt-in-it-using-xslt

Comment: I'm glad this helps.  You're welcome. Regarding your other question, does [Daniel Haley's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33810150/290085) not help?  Both he and I would have to hear from you regarding how it's not helping.  I recommend that you comment on his answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that this solution only works if (a) the processor supports disable-output-escaping, and (b) the output of the transformation is fed directly into a serializer.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Is there a more robust alternative to d-o-e that would work here?

Comment: @kjhughes: In 3.0 you could do `<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="param"/>` and then `<param>{serialize(*)}</param>`, but (a) this would make all param elements into CDATA sections, and (b) it would still only work if the transformer is coupled to a serializer - that's inevitable, really, because CDATA sections don't exist in the XDM data model. But the real requirement is probably not that the content is wrapped in CDATA, rather that the output contains a string of lexical XML rather than element markup, and in that sense this solution is more robust.